# Sum of array for same values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [TaxeName] => TPS
    [TaxeAmount] => 7
    [Price] => 14
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [TaxeName] => TVQ
    [TaxeAmount] => 9.975
    [Price] => 10
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [TaxeName] => TVQ
    [TaxeAmount] => 9.975
    [Price] => 18
  )
)
```

How I can get another array:
- Grouping the `TaxeName` and the `TaxeAmount` and
- Making the sum of the amount `Price` ?

Like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [TaxeName] => TPS
    [TaxeAmount] => 7
    [Price] => 14
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [TaxeName] => TVQ
    [TaxeAmount] => 9.975
    [Price] => 28
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a nested `foreach`:

```
$original = array(.......); // your current array
$newArr = array();

foreach($original as $origVal){
    $exists = false;
    foreach($newArr as $key => $newVal){
        if($newVal['TaxeName'] == $origVal['TaxeName']){
            $newArr[$key]['Price'] += $origVal['Price'];
            $exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$exists){
        $newArr[] = $origVal;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TaxeName] => TPS
            [TaxeAmount] => 7
            [Price] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TaxeName] => TVQ
            [TaxeAmount] => 9.975
            [Price] => 28
        )

)
```

Comment: This solution is wrong. It is not grouped according to TaxeName and TaxeAmount as required in the task, but only according to TaxeName.
The expected result only arises because the TaxeAmount for TVQ are also the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
$final = array();
foreach ($arr as $subarr)
{
    if (!isset($final[$subarr['TaxeName']]))
    {
        $final[$subarr['TaxeName']] = array('Price' => 0);
    }
    $final[$subarr['TaxeName']]['TaxeName'] = $subarr['TaxeAmount'];
    $final[$subarr['TaxeName']]['TaxeName'] = $subarr['TaxeName'];
    $final[$subarr['TaxeName']]['Price'] = $final[$subarr['TaxeName']]['Price'] + $subarr['Price'];
}
```

The idea is to make a new array with the values that you need and initializing it with the price set to 0 so you can increment it in the foreach

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also:

```
<?php

// Source
$myData = array(
    array(
        'TaxeName' => 'TPS',
        'TaxeAmount' => 7,
        'Price' => 14,
    ),
    array(
        'TaxeName' => 'TVQ',
        'TaxeAmount' => 9.975,
        'Price' => 10,
    ),
    array(
        'TaxeName' => 'TVQ',
        'TaxeAmount' => 9.975,
        'Price' => 18,
    )
);

// Helper Function
function parseData($data)
{
    $parsedData = array();

    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $dataItem) {
            if (!array_key_exists($dataItem['TaxeName'], $parsedData)) {
                $parsedData[$dataItem['TaxeName']] = array(
                    'TaxeName' => $dataItem['TaxeName'],
                    'TaxeAmount' => $dataItem['TaxeAmount'],
                    'Price' => floatval($dataItem['Price'])
                );
            } else {
                $parsedData[$dataItem['TaxeName']]['Price'] += floatval($dataItem['Price']);
            }
        }
    }

    return array_values($parsedData);
}

// Test
$parsed_data = parseData($myData);
var_dump($parsed_data);

?>
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: No need to use `is_array($data)`, you can just use `function parseData(array $data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function, input is your array, output is the array you required:

```
function calculate(array $input){
    $output = [];
    foreach ($input as $v){
        if (array_key_exists($v['TaxeName'], $output)){
            $output[$v['TaxeName']]['Price'] += $v['Price'];
        } else {
            $output[$v['TaxeName']] = $v;
        }
    }

    return array_values($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that solutions with external classes are not welcome here on SO. I'm showing this just to illustrate the "Grouping the TaxeName **and** the TaxeAmount" task.

```
//use class tablearray from https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray
$data = [
  ['TaxeName' => 'TPS', 'TaxeAmount' => 7, 'Price' => 14],
  ['TaxeName' => 'TVQ', 'TaxeAmount' => 9.975, 'Price' => 10],
  ['TaxeName' => 'TVQ', 'TaxeAmount' => 9.975, 'Price' => 18],
  ['TaxeName' => 'TVQ', 'TaxeAmount' => 19.975, 'Price' => 23]
];

$newData = tableArray::create($data)
  ->filterGroupSum('Price',['TaxeName','TaxeAmount'])
  ->fetchAll()
;

echo '<pre>';
var_export($newData);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'TaxeName' => 'TPS',
    'TaxeAmount' => 7,
    'Price' => 14,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'TaxeName' => 'TVQ',
    'TaxeAmount' => 9.975,
    'Price' => 28,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'TaxeName' => 'TVQ',
    'TaxeAmount' => 19.975,
    'Price' => 23,
  ),
)
```